# Parse Form Submission with Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, forms

I have a Google Spreadsheet that loads a sidebar with an HTML form. The code for that form is as follows:

```
<script>
function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
    google.script.run.processForm(formObject);

}
</script>
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
  PO#: <input type="text" name="po" required><br/>
  Invoice#: <input type="text" name="invoice" required><br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<div id="output"></div>
```

It works with the following script:

```
function processForm(form) {  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet5');
  var lr = sheet.getLastRow();
  var range = sheet.getRange(lr+1,1,1,1);
  range.setValue(form);
  Logger.log(form);
}
```

Currently I am getting `{invoice=####, po=####}` as a result. How can I parse (if that's even the right term) the form submission so that each response can go to a different cell? Is there any way to turn this into an array?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you want to do here, but I don't think you can transfer a dom object to Google Apps Script. You could use this:

```
<script>
function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
    google.script.run.processForm({
        po: formObject.getElementById("po").value,
        invoice: formObject.getElementById("invoice").value
    });

}
</script>
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
  PO#: <input type="text" name="po" id="po" required><br/>
  Invoice#: <input type="text" name="invoice" id="invoice" required><br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Then in your Google Apps Script, to get the values of the inputs, use

```
form.po
```

and

```
form.invoice
```

Comment: Apps Script processes the Form object before it's sent to the server, and strips out everything except the name and value.  The Form can be passed, *if* it is the only parameter value.  The server code can only get the values in the way that you already suggested.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I couldn't quite get this to work. Should `function processForm(form.po,form.invoice) {}` work?

Comment: For setting the cell value, you could do this `range.setValue(form.po+", "+form.invoice)` to include the values as strings.

Comment: Oh snap that was a lot closer to anything I have had yet. How would I use that to go across 2 cells if I changed the range to be 2 cells? `var range = sheet.getRange(lr+1,1,1,2);`

Comment: Never mind I got it! So my `handleFormSubmit(formObject)` is still the same as in my question but then I created an array using `form.po` and `form.invoice` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Using google.script.run.processForm() to pass back the form to the server. Instead of using get last row, and adding +1, just simply use appendRow() function.

```
    function processForm(form) {  
       var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
       var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet5');
       sheet.appendRow(form) //accepts an array [val1,val2,val3]
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Using `sheet.appendRow(form)` didn't result in anything on the spreadsheet.