# How do I get the value from a html element

Tags: html, google-apps-script

Hi im trying the get the value from a HTML element ID called "SBNum" and use it as a variable called SBNumber on a google script that then retrieves some data with an API.
Here's what I've got so far and I just can't get the value as a variable not sure what I'm missing.

**GS CODE**

```
    function doGet(request) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate();
}


/* @Include JavaScript and CSS Files */
function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}
/* @Process Form */


function processForm(formObject) {
     
var SBNumber = document.getElementById("SBNum").value;

///////////////////START API///////////////////////////
  
 
  var USERNAME = 'API PASSCODE';
  var PASSWORD = 'x';
  var url = 'https://URL/api/2.0/documents.json?documentNumber='+SBNumber+'&compact=false&contextId=5';
  var headers = {
    "Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(USERNAME + ':' + PASSWORD)
  };
```

**HTML CODE**

```
             <div class="form-row">
                  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                   <label for="SBNum">SalesBinder Number</label>
                   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="SBNum" >
                 </div>

              </div>
```

**JS CODE**

```
<script>
  // Prevent forms from submitting.
  function preventFormSubmit() {
    var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
    for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
      forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      
      });
    }
  }
  window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);  
   
      
      
  function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
    google.script.run.processForm(formObject);
    document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
    
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated
Thanks

Comment: If formObject is really a form object then formObject.name should work where name is the name attribute of some input element.  You don't have to use doGet() ... you could use google.script.run

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40229725/4935162)?

Comment: Hi Cooper thanks for the help I've tried using a few ways with no success 
var SBNumber = formObject.SBNum
var SBNumber = document.getElementById(formObject.SBNum).value;

Im I not coding it properly

Answer (score 1):

#### Modification points:

- There is no `document.getElementById("SBNum")` in Google Apps Script.
- In your Javascript, `handleFormSubmit` is not called.

Unfortunately, I cannot know your whole script. So, I would like to propose a modified script by complementing the script.

#### Modified script:

##### HTML side:

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label for="SBNum">SalesBinder Number</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="SBNum" name="SBNum">
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<script>
function preventFormSubmit() {
  var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
  for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
    forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var value = document.getElementById("myForm");
      handleFormSubmit(value);
    });
  }

  // or, I think that you can also use the following script instead of above script.
  // document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  //   event.preventDefault();
  //   var value = document.getElementById("myForm");
  //   handleFormSubmit(value);
  // });
}
window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);  
  
function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(_ => document.getElementById("myForm").reset()).processForm(formObject);
} 
</script>
```

##### Google Apps Script side:

In this modification, `processForm` is modified.

```js
function processForm(formObject) {
  var SBNumber = formObject.SBNum.value; // Retrieve values from HTML form.

  var USERNAME = 'API PASSCODE';
  var PASSWORD = 'x';
  var url = 'https://URL/api/2.0/documents.json?documentNumber=' + SBNumber + '&compact=false&contextId=5';
  var headers = {
    "Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(USERNAME + ':' + PASSWORD)
  };
  
  // do something


}
```

- When this modified HTML is opened and a value is put to the input tag and a submit button is clicked, the value of inputted value is sent to Google Apps Script. And, the value can be retrieved as `var SBNumber = formObject.SBNum.value`.

#### Note:

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- You can see the detail of this in my report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

#### References:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script (Author: me)](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)

Comment: @Yvan L Did my answer show you the result that you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue as you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. If you have issues with my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.